# An optimization problem of quadratic form

Tags: matrices, optimization

Giving a vector of length $m$: $a=[a_1,...,a_m]^T$, where $a_i\neq a_j, \forall 1\leq i<j\leq m$. I am considering an optimization problem as follows:
$$
\max_x \sum_{1\leq i < j \leq m}x_i x_j (a_i-a_j)^2=\frac12 x^TAx, s.t. 1^Tx=1, x\geq 0
$$
where the matrix $A\in R^{m\times m}$ and $[A]_{ij}=(a_i−a_j)^2$, and $1$ is a $m$-length vector of ones.

I can verify that the rank of $A$ is at most 3 (referring to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586178/rank-of-a-matrix-in-specific-form).

Since this is a non-convex optimization, I wonder whether there is a way to solve it (I tried Lagrangian method but didn't get a solution) and whether there is an analytic result for the optimization problem.

Comment: Are you aware of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming?

Comment: @flawr Does that mean any QP is solvable? And another problem is that $A$ is not invertible and in duality I see the form of inverse. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Non-convex QPs are very difficult to solve. You may need some kind of global solver to handle this. Here are some solvers that can handle these type of problems: [GloMIQO](http://helios.princeton.edu/GloMIQO/), [Baron](http://archimedes.cheme.cmu.edu/?q=baron), [Cplex](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/commerce/optimization/cplex-optimizer/).